# unique string count in a sequence

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I am trying to get the unique counts of the strings in a sequence.

For example,

```
 A<- c('CCE-CRE-DEE-DEE', 'FOE-FOE-GOE-GOE-GOE-ISE', 'ISE-PCE', 'ISE')
 library('stringr')
 B<- str_count(A, "-")
 df<- data.frame(A, B)
```

I am expecting output as follows:

C here is the total diversity, or different states in the sequence, any thoughts or suggestions? I looked around in SO but couldn't find a reasonable solution.

```
    df$C   
    4      
    3       
    2       
    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this using `unique`:

```
df$res <- sapply(str_split(A,"-"),function(x) length(unique(x)))
df
                        A B res
1         CCE-CRE-DEE-DEE 3   3
2 FOE-FOE-GOE-GOE-GOE-ISE 5   3
3                 ISE-PCE 1   2
4                     ISE 0   1
```

I supose that what you expect is actually 3 for `CCE-CRE-DEE-DEE`.